# Titanium Appaccelerator fails to install JDK

Tags: java, titanium, titanium-mobile

Whenever I try to install the Titanium Appaccelerator it always fails to install JDK 6 (or newer).

When Titanium starts, a background process starts to download the JDK, when the downloaded package is opened an exception is shown: "Isntalling JDK has encountered a problem". No more information or details are provided by the dialog.

Comment: JRE is installed or not,if not then install JRE ? you have to install 32-bit jdk .

Comment: Thanks Adnan for the tip, JRE is installed, this was more a self question-answer of an error that new users without the JDK might find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDK Path system variable may be missing.

Check the part "Updating the PATH Environment Variable (Optional)" from this manual: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path